# Can I use Spring Boot to make requests using someone elses API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

Im new to Spring and im trying to understand it. Is it possible for me to use Spring boot to make calls to someone else's api? for example, the api im using needs to be authenticated using credentials they give me. I would like to use their API to make POST requests. So far I have found documents that relate to using your own API. These requests require headers to be passed as well.

Whats the simplest way I can do a POST request, passing my credentials and the required headers using Spring ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use some HTTP client in your app to perform requests... It has nothing to do with Spring (only maybe if you wanted to use `RestTemplate`)

Comment: @michalk yea I want to use RestTemplate. I heard Spring makes it easier, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand u well, u need to post another web-api with credentials okay you can use

- restTemplate like the following example

```
 public List<EtisAccount> getAllActiveAccount(){
        logger.debug("Debug: in Class \t"+this.getClass().getName()+" Method Name is: \t"+new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        Properties sprinklrProp=sprinklrProperties.getSprinklrKeys();
        SprinklrCredential sprinklrCredential=credentialBuilder.getSprinklrCredential();
        RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setBearerAuth(sprinklrCredential.getAccess_token());
        header.add("key", sprinklrCredential.getApi_key());
        header.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder= UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(sprinklrProp.getProperty("sprinlrUri").toString())
                .queryParam("types", sprinklrProp.getProperty("accountTypes").toString());
        HttpEntity<String> entity= new HttpEntity<>(header);
        sslCertificateValidation.disable();
        ResponseEntity<String> sprinklrResponse=restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),HttpMethod.GET,entity,  String.class);
        List<EtisAccount> activeAccouts=etisAccountHelper.getAllSocialEtisAccounts(sprinklrResponse.getBody());
        logger.debug(String.valueOf(sprinklrResponse.getStatusCodeValue()));
        logger.debug(activeAccouts.toString());
        return activeAccouts;
    }
```

this is sample example for call online-API using RestTemplate

here i build header with credentials (bearer authentication)

```
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setBearerAuth(sprinklrCredential.getAccess_token());
        header.add("key", sprinklrCredential.getApi_key());
        header.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
```

and here i add header requestEntity to add to resttemplate request

```
     HttpEntity<String> entity= new HttpEntity<>(header);
```

and here i get response using exchange method

```
   ResponseEntity<String> sprinklrResponse=restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),HttpMethod.POST,entity,  String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need following things :

1. Create a Spring web starter project from https://start.spring.io/
2. Create a new Java Class in your project and name it `Controller`. Add `@RestController` annotation to on class level.
3. Configure `RestTemplate` object in SpringBootApplication
4. Autowire that `RestTemplate` object in `Controller` class
5. Create a method in `Controller` class which using `RestTemplate`, will call the `@PostMapping` to their API.

Answer (score -1):

- You can try this way
- This is the simple way to this
- You can set user name and password as basic Auth

```
  public class RESTInvoker {
        private final String baseUrl;
        private final String username;
        private final String password;

        public RESTInvoker(String baseUrl, String username, String password) {
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }



        String getDataFromServer(String path) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl + path);
                URLConnection urlConnection = setUsernamePassword(url);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();

                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private URLConnection setUsernamePassword(URL url) throws IOException {
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            String authString = username + ":" + password;
            String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            return urlConnection;
        }
    }
```